# What is the basic difference between interpolation & inference?

Tags: logic, statistical-inference, interpolation, lagrange-interpolation, interpolation-theory

In mathematics we've studied interpolation as predicting the structure of a function from it's given finitely many values from which consequently we use to construct certain function which nearly resembles after the earlier one; obviously with some errors in it.  On the other hand,  statistically saying, inference is actually a procedure of drawing reasonable conclusion about entire population from merely given sample or data set & eventually error occurs here also. Aren't these two concepts same- not in letter though but in spirit in some way?

Comment: Interpolation is about numerical values. Inference is about propositions/sentences.

Comment: But we've also inferred numerical characteristics of statistical population using data set extracted from random sample. What about that?